# Action view::template::error (Unexpected token: operator (<))

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

im getting a problem with my deploy at heroku! 
I just created an app Test with cedar stack, push my app and I have this problem (log)

```
←[32m2012-03-24T15:10:56+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m ActionView::Template::Error (Unexpected token: operator (<)
←[32m2012-03-24T15:10:56+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   (in /app/app/assets/javascripts/application.js)):
←[32m2012-03-24T15:10:56+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     3: <head>
←[32m2012-03-24T15:10:56+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     4:   <title>Test</title>
←[32m2012-03-24T15:10:56+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
←[32m2012-03-24T15:10:56+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     6:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
←[32m2012-03-24T15:10:56+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
←[32m2012-03-24T15:10:56+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     8: </head>
←[32m2012-03-24T15:10:56+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     9: <body>
```

Any Idea??

**Update**:

My application.js file

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into including all the files listed below.
// Add new JavaScript/Coffee code in separate files in this directory and they'll automatically
// be included in the compiled file accessible from http://example.com/assets/application.js
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// the compiled file.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: Probably something funky going on in `application.js`. Have you checked that it works properly in localhost?

Comment: Yes, in my local server apps works correctly.

Comment: Does it work properly *in production mode* (with assets precompiled) on your local machine? Do you have any non-js/coffee files under the /app/assets/javascript directory?

Comment: No, only application.js and all .js.coffee files generated by rails

Comment: Did you have any luck in resolving this? I'm having the same error...

Comment: Try removing `//= require` lines one-by-one to see which one is causing the error. What other JS/CS files are included with the `require_tree .` call?

Comment: @josephvilla nope, I just gave up long time ago :(!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this error and it took a while to figure out which file referenced in the manifest was the culprit. Once I figured out which file was causing the error, searching for '>' pulled up several lines but I got lucky and quickly zeroed in a map function which used the `=>` operator:

`.map(x => x.id);`

Once I changed that to an anonymous function:

`.map(function(x) { return x.id; });`

the error went away.

Comment: But how to make rails supports ES7?

Answer (score 0):

I've just run into this problem, and the trick was that there was a remaining line of a conflict between the server and my localhost. In my localhost everything seamed fine, but i think that's because of some cache, or something. Anyway, i opened the application.js and remove the lines with the << HEAD...

I let it here for register of the problem and a possible solution

Answer (score 0):

> ***NOTE:** it's been almost 7 years since the OP asked this question. The issue I experienced is likely a newer problem (with the same error log output as OP). The below answer likely doesn't apply to the issue the OP experienced, but could be helpful to new visitors looking for a solution.*
>   **My Rails version:** `5.1.2`

## Found the problem

It was an issue with how **Production** handles my `assets.precompile` (in `config/initializers/assets.rb`)

After trial-and-error to find the culprit (a new JS file I created a week ago), I noticed the error vanished after commenting out the line that includes the file in `config/initializers/assets.rb`.

```
# Commented out until precompile fix found
# Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( break_the_project.js )
```

---

### THE FIX

Since this only happened in **Production** for me, I updated `config/environments/production.rb`, replacing the line:

```
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
```

to:

```
config.assets.js_compressor = Uglifier.new(harmony: true)
```

After restarting the Rails server, my World was peaceful once again.

***[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49236329/1180523)***