# ExecJS::RuntimeError: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: name (catch) (line: 41, col: 8, pos: 1392)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, service-worker

I'm trying to add a service worker to my Rails app with the serviceworker gem.

I've been following this guide https://rossta.net/blog/offline-page-for-your-rails-application.html and started receiving the error listed in the title.

I've reviewed other questions similar, but most are due to syntax errors. As this post [Rails 5 Heroku deploy error: ExecJS::ProgramError: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: name (autoRegisterNamespace)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39221152/rails-5-heroku-deploy-error-execjsprogramerror-syntaxerror-unexpected-token)

My error is due to the token name (catch) which was supplied via the serviceworker gem file.

Here is my code where the error is occurring ...

```
 function onFetch(event) {
   // Fetch from network, fallback to cached content, then offline.html for same-origin GET requests
   var request = event.request;

   if (!request.url.match(/^https?:\/\/example.com/) ) { return; }
   if (request.method !== 'GET') { return; }

   event.respondWith(
     fetch(request).                                       // first, the network
        .catch(function fallback() {
          caches.match(request).then(function(response) {  // then, the cache
            response || caches.match("/offline.html.erb");     // then, /offline cache
          })
        })
    );
```

I understand the error is at .catch , I'm just not sure how to solve the issue.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: That was it, the (.) at the end of fetch was causing the error. I overlooked it because it nothing was raised about being a syntax issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax error with two dots.  The line break sometimes makes it hard to notice.

```
 event.respondWith(
 fetch(request).    // Dot here and then...
    .catch(function fallback() { // ... the one at beginning of line as well causes the issue...
      caches.match(request).then(function(response) {  // then, the cache
        response || caches.match("/offline.html.erb");     // then, /offline cache
      })
    })
);
```

Should be

```
 event.respondWith(
 fetch(request)                                     // remove dot 
    .catch(function fallback() {
      caches.match(request).then(function(response) {  // then, the cache
        response || caches.match("/offline.html.erb");     // then, /offline cache
      })
    })
);
```